# Double quotes are no getting removed even after using org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde

Tags: hive, hive-serde

I am having an external table with DDL as below  :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE pathirippilly_db.serdeTest (Name varchar(50),Job varchar(50),Sex varchar(4))
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
(
    "separatorChar" = ",",
    "quoteChar"     = "\""
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location "/user/pathirippilly/hive_data_external/serdeTest";
```

After creating the table with above DDL, I am inserting the data as below:

```
insert into serdetest values('"AKHIL"','Engineer','Male');
```

But still the double quotes are not getting escaped (not getting removed) even after opencsv serde is defined. So here are my question

1. Where I am going wrong
2. Say If I am having multiple quoteChar to be escaped, for example, I need to remove both single and double quotes from my input data. How can I achieve this using opencsv serde.
3. As per Apache [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde#CSVSerde-Usage][1]
   even if I have not defined the quoteChar and escapeChar, it should automatically pick double quotes with escape char as "\" and should automatically remove double quotes from data. But why its not happening in my code

Answer (score 0):

**Both 1st and 3rd question are similar - Why double quotes are not removed?**

This is because SerDe is not used when inserting data directly into table. SerDe stands for Serializer/Deserializer and Hive uses it to read/write table rows from/to file.

> HDFS files --> InputFileFormat -->  --> Deserializer -->
>   Row object
>
> Row object --> Serializer -->  --> OutputFileFormat -->
>   HDFS files

Try inserting data into your hive table using 'load' command and you could see it working.

```
load data local inpath '/home/hive/test/test.csv' into table serdetest;
```

**Sample - test.csv**

```
"AKHIL",Engineer,Male
```

For more details, please check [Hive Wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DeveloperGuide#DeveloperGuide-HiveSerDe).

**2nd question - How to escape multiple quote characters?**

This can be done using '[RegexSerDe](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-662)'.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE serdetest (Name varchar(50),Job varchar(50),Gender 
varchar(6))
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'input.regex' = '^\"(\\d+)\\W+\\W+(\\w+).*'
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location "/user/pathirippilly/hive_data_external/serdeTest";
```

**Note: Regex given in the statement is for example, not actual.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works perfectly fine. Thanks.

But then I have a question. In my project , source file is getting placed via a shell script into a stage table location (which is in AWS s3 bucket). And stage to target we are loading through spark code. Now since the file is getting placed directly , I can not use LOAD INPATH command for loading data. As a work around , I am using REGEX_REPLACE or substring to remove the quotes. So in this scenario, is there any chance that we can implement  SERDE

Comment: I have just tested the above scenario by defining the stage table with openCSV serde and placing the file on target location and its working fine now. Thanks !!!

Comment: I had used the Load into table , but still it is not working. I am still seeing the data are getting into wrong column.
This is my sample data. Column 2 is getting seperated.
`"5f367c99e4b0799af79a2b89","The Washingtons: George and Martha, "Join'd by Friendship, Crown'd by Love"",""`